# looping through php table is not working [Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting this error on my index.php page where i have also included the code

```
<?pho
require 'connect.php';
?>
```

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'menulinks'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li>', $row['linktitle'], '<li>';

}
    ?>
```

Here is my connect function

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Sorry, we could not connect');
mysql_select_db('philipsnewsite', $con) or die('Sorry, we could not connect');

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quoted your table name in single-quote characters, which MySQL interprets as a string literal.  You should either use backticks, or no quote characters at all:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `menulinks`";
```

This syntax error caused the `mysql_query()` function to return false, which you can test as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also note, as documented in a **big red box** at the top of the manual page for [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> #### Suggested alternatives
>
> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
> - [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: @Philip, if this answered your question, please select the "mark as answer" icon.